# How would I create a dropbox style loading screen over a tabBarcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, dropbox

I tried doing this:

```
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview: myViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

However, the subview does not cover the entire screen, some of the tabbar is still showing at the bottom. Also, how would i get the loading screen to disappear after the application has finished loading?

Comment: A screenshot of what you're trying to replicate might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your loading view as a subview to the window. That will cover everything except the status bar (which you can't cover, only hide).